# Splitting a column into two columns base on a separator in csv file using Awk?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I'm new to shell scripting. I have a csv file *"a.csv"* with 15000 rows and 15 columns. It has one column named *"id_data"*.

It is always column 3 in a.csv file.

The values in this dataset looks like this:

```
A,B,id_data,C,D,E,F,...
a,b,12345_85485,c,d,e,f,...
a,b,45786_456322,c,d,e,f,...
a,b,12345_325489,c,d,e,f,...
a,b,_45230_14693,c,d,e,f....
```

where a-f columns data ranges from numbers to date,strings,links.

I want to count the unique values in column 3 after the *'_'* symbol.

For that, I want to split this column based on number before `_` and number after `_` into two different columns namely "ID1 data" and "ID2 Data". The splitting is not mandatory though. Main aim is to calculate the unique numbers after the *'_'* in column 3.

The output should look like this in the csv file:

```
A,B,ID1 Data,ID2 Data,D,E,F...
a,b,12345,85485,d,e,f,...
a,b,45786,456322,d,e,f,...
a,b,12345,325489,d,e,f,...
a,b,45230,4693,d,e,f,...
```

I have tried doing it using the following command:

```
cat a.csv | sed -Ee 's/(.*)id_data/\1ID1 Data ID2 Data/' -e 's/,[_ ]/,/' -e 's/_/,/'
```

It printed the output as per the requirement. But there is no changes in the columns of the csv file. The o/p printed looks like *a,b,12345,85485,c,d,e,f,...*.

How can I apply the change to the columns in the csv file? Any advice would be helpful. Thanks

*Please note that at the beginning there could be space or even '_'.

Comment: I suggest to remove first leading space and `_` and then replace `_` with space.

Comment: You write `"a.csv" with 15000 rows and 15 columns`, but later you write `into two different columns`.  Do you have 2 or 15 columns?

Comment: @Jotne It seems, the file has 15 columns but OP wants to focus on this particular column only. So this one could be 1st or 14th column. who knows :)

Comment: If your real data has 15 columns, don't just show 1 in your example as that's not representative of your real data and doesn't provide something adequate to test a potential solution against - show at least 3 columns with the target one in the middle. Also clarify if `id_data` is always the Nth column or if you need to find that column by it's name on the header line.

Comment: Sure. Please have a look at my edited  question. Thanks @Ed Morton

Comment: Much better (but you could stand to get rid of the `...`s at the end of each line as they're adding no value, presumably don't **really** exist in your real data, and are just cluttering up your example). I updated my answer to match your updated example.

Comment: @klam do you want to count the unique values of "ID2 Data" field? Of those of  "ID1 Data"? Or of both?

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, this is a Generic solution where we need not to hard code value of field in solution, it will look for string `id_data` in first line gets its column number and acts accordingly for rest of the lines of Input_file.

`awk 'FNR==1{for(j=1;j<=NF;j++){if($j=="id_data"){field=j;$j="ID1_data  ID2_data"}};print;next}  {sub(/^_/,"",$field); sub(/_/,OFS,$field)}  1' Input_file`

Adding a non-one liner form of solution:

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  for(j=1;j<=NF;j++){
    if($j=="id_data"){
      field=j
      $j="ID1_data  ID2_data"
    }    
  }
  print
  next
}
{
  sub(/^_/,"",$field)
  sub(/_/,OFS,$field)
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** Please add `BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}` in above code in case your Input_file it comma separated.

***Explanation:***

```
awk '                                ##Starting awk program here.
FNR==1{                              ##Checking condition if FNR==1 which will be TRUE for 1st line.
  for(j=1;j<=NF;j++){                ##Started a for loop from j=1 to till value of NF here.
    if($j=="id_data"){               ##Checking condition if current field is equal to id_data then do following.
      field=j                        ##Setting field variable value to variable j value.
      $j="ID1_data  ID2_data"        ##Setting current field value to string ID1_data space ID2_data here.
    }
  }
  print                              ##Printing current line.
  next                               ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  sub(/^_/,"",$field)                ##Using substitute function to substitute starting _ with NULL in $field, where field is a variable set in first line.
  sub(/_/,OFS,$field)                ##Using substitute function to substitute  _ with OFS for $field field.
}
1                                    ##Mentioning 1 will print edited/non-edited lines.
'  Input_file                        ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** As per OP's comment:

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
FNR==1{
  for(j=1;j<=NF;j++){
    if($j=="id_data"){
      field=j
      $j="ID1_data  ID2_data"
    }    
  }
  print
  next
}
{
  sub(/^_/,"",$field)
  sub(/.*_/,OFS,$field)
}
1
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding a solution not awk based.

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and starting from

```
A,B,id_data,C,D,E,F,...
a,b,12345_85485,c,d,e,f,...
a,b,45786_456322,c,d,e,f,...
a,b,12345_325489,c,d,e,f,...
a,b,_45230_14693,c,d,e,f....
```

and then running

```
mlr --csv --ragged cut -f id_data then nest --explode --values --across-records --nested-fs "_" -f id_data then skip-trivial-records then uniq -a -c input.csv >output.csv
```

you will have

```
count,id_data
2,12345
1,85485
1,45786
1,456322
1,325489
1,45230
1,14693
```

If you want the output of your question, you could run

```
mlr --csv --ragged put -S '$id_data=gsub($id_data,"^([^-0-9]+)([0-9])(.+)","\2\3")' then nest --explode --values --across-fields --nested-fs "_" -f id_data then unsparsify input.csv  >output.csv
```

and obtain

```
A,B,id_data_1,id_data_2,C,D,E,F,...
a,b,12345,85485,c,d,e,f,...
a,b,45786,456322,c,d,e,f,...
a,b,12345,325489,c,d,e,f,...
a,b,45230,14693,c,d,e,f....,
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do some like this:

```
awk -F'_' -v OFS='\t' '{sub(/^[_ ]/,"");$1=$1}1' file
id      data
12345   85485
45786   456322
12345   325489
45230   14693
```

Header formating

```
awk -F'_' -v OFS='\t\t' 'NR==1 {print $1"1 "$2"\t"$1"2 "$2;next}{sub(/^[_ ]/,"");$1=$1}1' file
id1 data        id2 data
12345           85485
45786           456322
12345           325489
45230           14693
```

This is based on Pacifists solution so he could see what needed to be fixed to get it working:

```
awk -F'[_ ]' 'BEGIN {print "ID1 Data\tID2 Data"} NR>1{print $(NF-1)"\t\t"$NF}' file
ID1 Data        ID2 Data
12345           85485
45786           456322
12345           325489
45230           14693
```

Change `$NF-1` to `$(NF-1)` and `-F'_'` change to `-F'[_ ]'` to get rid of the space

Comment: Thanks, Jotne. I actually got the NF field wrong that I realized but then leading space was also problematic for me so I'm using sub now but `-F'[_ ]'` looks easier :). I undeleted my post now.

Comment: @Pacifist I tried to comment your post, but not possible when its deleted :)  PS it may be that OP has more than 2 columns, 15?

Comment: That's true. It is mentioned also that columns are around 15, I was only focusing on the sample file. In that case, mine would be a complete failure. I should actually delete it again :).

Comment: Yes @Pacifist, the csv file contains 15 columns. The id_data column is 4th column. After adding a new column the count will increased to 16. Or else we can just remove everything before '_' and just let the column "id_data" contain the number after '_'. How can we just delete the everything before '_' ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

If there are more than 2 columns (n number of columns)

```
cat file
id_data
12345_85485_243524_435
45786_456322_2435_2345
 12345_325489_2435_45
_45230_14693_2345_453
```

Then this may do:

```
awk -F'_' 'NR>1{sub(/^ /,"");for (i=($1?1:2);i<=NF;i++) printf "%s\t\t",$i;print ""}' file
12345           85485           243524          435
45786           456322          2435            2345
12345           325489          2435            45
45230           14693           2345            453
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {n=split($3,f,/[ _]/); $3=(NR>1 ? f[n-1] OFS f[n] : "ID1 Data" OFS "ID2 Data")} 1' file
A,B,ID1 Data,ID2 Data,C,D,E,F,...
a,b,12345,85485,c,d,e,f,...
a,b,45786,456322,c,d,e,f,...
a,b,12345,325489,c,d,e,f,...
a,b,45230,14693,c,d,e,f....
```

Comment: it gave an output like this   A,,B,id_data,C,D,E,F,  not like this A,B,ID1 Data,Id2 Data,C,D,E,F . Please note that I have added two commas after A for the output.

Comment: As you can see in my answer, the script I posted produces the output you said you wanted from the input you provided. If you're getting some different result when you execute it then either a) you didn't copy/paste my script correctly or b) the input you're running it against isn't the same as the input in your question. It is completely impossible for my script to produce the output you say it does - for example it **WILL** print `ID1 Data,ID2 Data` in the first line of output no matter what your input looks like.

Comment: Hey @EdMorton, Sorry for my earlier comments. I have checked the code i copied and found that I copied a single line wrong. After my rectification,it was working absolutely fine. I just wrote the output to a new file and it had two new rows. Sorry once again. Thanks for the answer.Kudos.

Comment: Is there any possible way of counting the unique numbers in the id_data column , after underscore('_') seperator, without splitting it into two separate columns? @EdMorton. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't know exactly what that means but in general - it's only software so I expect the answer would be "yes". Please finish off the question you asked by accepting one of the answers and then ask a new question with it's own concise, testable sample input/output if you have one.